# Pending Review counter still showing after review ban

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-suspension

I got banned from reviewing, after one wrong review, for a month.

But the icon for pending review is still showing in a orange colour, which is taking out my attention sometimes.

Why is it there if I can't review it?

[image]