# How can I hide review notifications?

Tags: support, review-queues

In the recently redesigned header on Stack Overflow, review notifications were introduced:

[image]

Is there an option to hide review notifications? They distract me.

Comment: Hum, they were also present before?

Comment: _"review notifications were introduced"_ Actually, they weren't _introduced_ here. THey've been around for a while.

Comment: @Kendra Were they that visible? I think it was more like a count, not a notification.

Comment: Also, why should questions on the  redesigned header be asked on stack overflow meta? Isn't the  redesigned header  meant to be for all Stack Exchange websites?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's rolled out only on SO for now. That's why Meta.SE is not the best place for questions regarding it.

Comment: 1) Not sure, trying to find old screenshots on other posts to see. 2) The header is only for SO at the moment. No one else will see it for a bit, so it should go here.

Comment: @Kendra ok looking forward to seeing the duplicate questions on SE meta when the header gets deployed on other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Just load up stylish or greasemonkey and inject the following CSS: `.indicator-badge.js-unread-count._reviews { display: none }`

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's basically exactly the same- The only difference is it's now placed as an indicator on the review button, instead of beside it. [This post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314892/pending-review-counter-still-showing-after-review-ban) has a picture showing it. It also _is_ more visible now if you have the sticky header enabled.

Comment: The notification number isn't new. What *is* new, is that the header is present all the time, where previously even the slightest scroll puts it out of view. (You can disable the stickiness in your preferences).

Comment: @Kendra thanks good point, I forgot it was that visible. I guess I got used to it.

Comment: @Andy thanks good to know that stickiness may be disabled.

Comment: Another aspect is that it's now right next to the inbox, so it takes more mental effort to differentiate "pending inbox items" and "pending reviews". Previously they were on opposite sides of the top bar from each other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since there seems to be no option to disable those annoying notifications, I use the Google Chrome extension [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US) to remove the icon. It takes around five seconds:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone is interested in blocking the badges/reputations as well as review counts on all Stack Exchange websites, here are the filters I use:

```
stackexchange.com##.topbar-icon.icon-achievements.yes-hover.js-achievements-button
stackoverflow.com##.\-link.js-review-button
stackoverflow.com##.\-link.js-achievements-button
stats.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count
academia.stackexchange.com##.topbar-icon.icon-flag.icon-tools-flag.yes-hover
superuser.com##.topbar-icon.icon-achievements.yes-hover.js-achievements-button
softwarerecs.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count
health.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count
*.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count
*.stackexchange.com##.topbar-icon.icon-flag.icon-tools-flag.yes-hover
*##.topbar-icon.icon-achievements.yes-hover.js-achievements-button
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple option is to use *[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)* (available for Firefox and Google) and add this piece of CSS:

```
.js-review-button > .indicator-badge {
    display: none; 
}
```

Then it will never be shown again.

Comment: where should I add

Comment: Why is an add-on required? Couldn't it be done by [editing file "userContent.css"](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257) in folder `chrome` under a user profile? (Not rhetorical questions.)